# Web Analytics files keep piling up

Tags: kentico

[image]

Looking at the above image, you can see that the Web Analytics files keep accumulating on the web server. The location is

> ~App_Data\CMSModules\WebAnalytics

The CMS website is on 3 web servers which are load balanced but this issue is happening on only one of them. Gave Full permissions to "Network Service" & "IIS_IUSRS" user accounts on that folder and still the files are not getting deleted. Is this a setting in Kentico that I can set or some simple permissions issue that I am overlooking.

Comment: Did you always have 3 servers in the farm, or is one of them a recent addition.  If the scheduled task is set to run in the external service, are you sure that it has been installed on the 3rd server?

Comment: The 3 servers have always been there. Not sure about the scheduled tasks. Where can I check for the scheduled task?

Comment: If you open **Scheduled tasks** and search for a task named *Remove analytics data*, that will tell you how the task is configured.  This has a checkbox named *'Use external service'*.

Comment: Also, the default setup for *Remove analytics data* is to run every month.  Or do you think it is the *Process analytics log* task (which probably runs every minute) that is failing?  Is there anything in the Kentico event log perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to call wrong on other people, but in this case *Remove Analytics Data* will not help. This task will delete only data from database, not from file system.

These log files are something which should be removed immediately after different task is finished. This should be **Process analytics log** task.

It is one of the tasks, which needs to tun on every server in web farm:

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/optimizing-website-performance/setting-up-web-farms/configuring-web-farm-servers#Configuringwebfarmservers-Configuringscheduledtaskstobeexecutedoneveryserverofawebfarm

Comment: You are spot on. The job on that server seems to have struck. I disabled & re-enabled it and it started working.